# Extracting a value from a file containing multiple lines

Tags: python

I am trying to search a string that contains a line  `'<text> 291 km</text>'` and just return the value of `291`. When I run the code below I get an error -

```
print m.group(1) 
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Python beginner here!

```
   f = open("sample.txt","r+") 
   text = f.read()
   m = re.search('<text> (.+?)km</text>', text)
   print m.group(1)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? it should be clear that your regex has failed, what is the value of text when this fails?

Comment: post the content of your text file.

Comment: I have added the text file and you can see the line with the 255km that I want to extract - all I need is the 255 value. Thanks

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dE1DjqPnCmTlVYZXVybXlpTDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's probably because of spaces exists between those words. I suggest you to use `\s*` to match in-between zero or more spaces.

```
>>> s = 'foo <text> 291 km</text> bar'
>>> re.search(r'<text>\s*(\d+)\s*km\s*</text>', s).group(1)
'291'
```

Comment: *because of spaces exists between those strings*? I think it should be between the *words* in the string! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If that is an actual separate  line in your file and it always starts with `<text>` you can use str.startswith and split:

```
with open("tsample.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.startswith( '<text>' ):
            print(line.split()[1])
291
```

Either way you should use `with` to open the file and read line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I will use the with in my code